# procedure to find numbers divisible by 3 and by 2 between 1-100

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

i have assignment , to make procedure determine numbers divisible by 3 and 2 , but i just can try divisible by both 3 and 2 , like this

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `divisible`()
BEGIN
  declare str VARCHAR(255) default '';
  declare x INT ;



  SET x = 1;
  set str = '';

while x <= 100 do

    if (x mod 3=0 &&  x mod 2 =0)  then 
        set str= CONCAT(str, x ,',')  ;  

    end if;
    set x=x+1;

end while;

SELECT str ;
END
```

Output from procedure above : `'6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60,66,72,78,84,90,96,'`

how to make different output, so divisible by 3 : 3,6,9,12 ... and by 2 : 2,4,6,8 between 1-100.

Comment: what is the question? Procedure looks ok.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: you can do this by simple query why need procedure

Comment: @jaidutt I dont see a simple query for that. Maybe you can show it as an answer

Comment: @jaidutt my assignment , so i must follows the rule

Comment: Wow! Worst use of SQL. Ever!! :-)

Comment: Be advised that SQL is not a panacea.

Comment: this assignment using sql just test student for their logic, not for making program for the future. teacher can order use other language programming. but focus more to sql only

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you can get the list of numbers divisible by both two and three, by simply realising that's all the multiples of six:

```
set m = 6;
set x = m;
set str = '';
while x <= 100 do
    set str = CONCAT(str, x ,',');
    set x = x + m;
end while;
```

And, of course, you can use that same method to get a list of *any* multiples by simply changing the multiplier `m` to something else.

---

If you want the numbers that are divisible by two *or* three (rather than two *and* three), you just need to change your original code to use `or` instead of `and`:

```
if (x mod 3 = 0 || x mod 2 = 0)  then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET x = 1;
set str2 = '2: ';
set str3 = '3: ';
set str23 = '2|3: ';

while x <= 100 do

    if (x mod 2 = 0)  then 
        set str2 = CONCAT(str, x ,',')  ;      
    end if;

    if (x mod 3 = 0)  then 
        set str3 = CONCAT(str, x ,',')  ;      
    end if;

    if (x mod 2 = 0 &&  x mod 3 = 0)  then 
        set str23= CONCAT(str, x ,',')  ;      
    end if;
    set x=x+1;

end while;

SELECT str2
UNION
SELECT str3
UNION
SELECT str23
;
END
```

Comment: your procedure just can read str2 only. thats my problem, is sql procedure just can display one output? or we must try use concat?
`SELECT concat("result_1: ", str2, "result_2: ", str3,"result_3",str23 ) AS "divisible"`; but result different :\